# Il serait / sera / est préférable

Tags: conditionnel

Bonjour,

A demande à plusieurs personnes quelle option ils préfèrent, il y en a deux. Il agira selon leurs réponses.

B lui répond :

> Pour ma part, il serait préférable de faire ceci (option 1)

D'après ce [fil](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/toute-aide-serait-sera-appr%C3%A9ci%C3%A9e-appr%C3%A9ciable.2768500/), le conditionnel indique ici que B n'est pas sûr que A choisisse la première option. Est-ce que c'est aussi une manière plus polie de s'exprimer ?

Answer (score 3):

L'emploi du conditionnel souligne en effet l'aspect incertain de cette "validation" de l'option 1. Le doute suggéré peut être réel, ou effectivement une forme de politesse: on affirme, mais on laisse la porte ouverte à une éventuelle remarque. "Il est préférable de ..." est plus direct, j'oserais dire plus affirmatif.

La nuance est subtile, mais je ne serais pas étonné de découvrir que des formations en assertivité ou en management déconseillent l'emploi du conditionnel pour l'une ou l'autre raison comme paraître plus sur de soi.

Comment: On peut aussi le dire quand ce choix est le moins mauvais de tous parmi ceux possibles.